# Extracting BZ2 compressed folder using Python

Tags: python, compression

I am trying to extract a `bz2` compressed folder in a specific location.
I can see the data inside by :

```
handler = bz2.BZ2File(path, 'r')
print handler.read()
```

But I wish to extract all the files in this compressed folder into a location (specified by the user) maintaining the internal directory structure of the folder.

I am fairly new to this language .. Please help...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like gzip, BZ2 is only a compressor for single files, it can not archive a directory structure. What I suspect you have is an archive that is first created by a software like `tar`, that is then compressed with `BZ2`. In order to recover the "full directory structure", first extract your Bz2 file, then un-tar (or equivalent) the file.

Fortunately, the Python [tarfile](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html) module supports bz2 option, so you can do this process in one shot.

Comment: And how to I do that ?  the extracting BZ2 file part ?? Is there a function through which I directly get the uncompressed file or do I need to read the bz2 file first and then write that data to some other file ?

Comment: Open a tar.bz file as if it was an ordinary tar file. The Python tarfile module will take care of the rest.

Answer (score 2):

[bzip2](http://www.bzip.org/) is a data compression system which compresses one entire file. It does not bundle files and compress them like [PKZip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKZIP) does. Therefore `handler` in your example has one and only one file in it and there is no "internal directory structure".

If, on the other hand, your file is actually a compressed tar-file, you should look at the [tarfile module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html) of Python which will handle decompression for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [tarfile](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html) module to uncompress a `.tar.bz2` file ... from the docs here is how you can do it:

```
import tarfile
tar = tarfile.open(path, "r:bz2")
for tarinfo in tar:
    print tarinfo.name, "is", tarinfo.size, "bytes in size and is",
    if tarinfo.isreg():
        print "a regular file."
        # read the file
        f = tar.extractfile(tarinfo)
        print f.read()
    elif tarinfo.isdir():
        print "a directory."
    else:
        print "something else."
tar.close()
```